# React/Redux, how to get user's input?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've got stuck at doing a test assignment. Something I really don't get is how to retrieve user input.
Yes I've seen similar question but the didn't helped me. Here's a part of components code that  contains input
   / [Link to the actual code on the gist.github.com](https://gist.github.com/Y-Taras/42de4caa1ab4b2210f0d17eea83da457) /

[image]

**...**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it should be `evt.target.value` instead.

Comment: Yes I've already changed my code the way you've said but the code still doesn't work properly, though error's in console disappear

Comment: Can you console.log(evt.target.value) inside handleFilterTermChange and tell me what you get?

Comment: yep I used redux tools and see that  input value is in the state/ but why {this.props.filterVal} doesn't show me anything on the page

Comment: I am assuming `setFilterTerm` set `searchTerm` of your redux state? If so could you console.log(state.searchTerm) and console.log(filterTerm) before the return value in mapStateToProps and tell me what you get?

Comment: Yep you've found my typo!! I changed that string to const filterTerm =  state.filterTerm ? state.filterTerm : ""; and it worked. Thanks. And One more thing  --- Three  inputs  will work properly with e.target .value?